# System log error when running Firestarter configuration program

Tags: configuration, system, firewall, log

Running latest Ubuntu ver. 11.04. Using Firestarter firewall configuration (ver.1.0.3). When Firestarter is run, an error message is returned, "Failed to open the system log. No event information will be available". Also same error msg. is returned in the "Events" tab within Firestater, "Error reading system log (null), file does not exist."

How is the system log opened/created/started to prevent this error msg??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ubuntu 11.04 installs `rsylogd` rather than `syslogd` which Firestarter was expecting.

`rsyslogd` is configured using the file `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`.

You can edit this file

```
gksu gedit /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf
```

and change the lines commented out that create the relevant logfile

```
#*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
# auth,authpriv.none;\
# cron,daemon.none;\
# mail,news.none -/var/log/messages
```

to

```
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        cron,daemon.none;\
        mail,news.none -/var/log/messages
```

and then restart rsyslog:

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

[source](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firestarter/+question/155614)

Comment: @fossfreedom, Thank you. I have some problem with `/ets/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`, when i try to save the edits in, it give me error: `Error writing /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf: Read-only file system`

Comment: @shgnInc - a read-only file system is symptomatic of other issues - usually your filesystem needs to be fsck'd.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the other methdods posted about here, you can just put a symbolic link in `/var/log` that points `messages` to `syslog`:

```
cd /var/log
sudo ln -s syslog messages
```